# How to combine unitest textrunner log with logging

Tags: python, unit-testing

How to log the debug or info comments to the generated log file from python unit test

```
import unittest
import logging

class Arming(unittest.TestCase):
    def testCase1(self):
        logging.info('I told you so')
        actual = 3
        expected = 3
        self.assertEqual(actual,expected)

    def testCase2(self):
        actual = 3
        expected = 4
        testcase = "Test Case 2"
        self.assertEqual(actual,expected)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   log_file = 'Arming_Command.log'
   f = open(log_file, "w")
   runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(f,verbosity=2)
   unittest.main(testRunner=runner)
   f.close()
```

Getting log file

```
testCase1 (__main__.Arming) ... ok
testCase2 (__main__.Arming) ... FAIL

======================================================================
FAIL: testCase2 (__main__.Arming)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hariom.singh/PycharmProjects/Connect_Pversion/venv/Python_Logging.py", line 15, in testCase2
    self.assertEqual(actual,expected)
AssertionError: 3 != 4

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.001s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

logging.info('I told you so')
is missed in the log file

Comment: print (logging.getLevelName()) please. You may simply not have "info" enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You failed to configure the logging module to use the specified file. You can use `basicConfig` for that. Code could become:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
   log_file = 'Arming_Command.log'
   f = open(log_file, "w")
   logging.basicConfig(stream=f, level=logging.INFO)  # use the opened file for logging
   runner = unittest.TextTestRunner(f,verbosity=2)
   unittest.main(testRunner=runner)
   f.close()
```